# How to prove a complex function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider a complex function $f(z)$. Suppose it's analytic in $|z|<1$ and continuous in $|z|\leq 1$. If $f(z)\in\mathbf{R}$ on the boundary $|z|=1$, how to prove it's a real constant in $|z|\leq 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is uniformly continuous we have that for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for every point $w \in \mathbb C$ with $|w| = 1- \delta$ we have that the imaginary part of $f(w)$ is at most $\varepsilon$. Compute 
$$\text{im }f(z) = \text{im }\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|w|=1-\delta}\frac{f(w)}{w-z}\,dw<\varepsilon.$$
Letting $\varepsilon$ go to $0$ we obtain that $f(z) \in \mathbb R$.
Since holomorphic functions with image in $\mathbb R$ are constant (e.g., by the Cauchy-Riemann equations), $f$ is constant.

Comment: This is wrong: $f$ need not admit a holomorphic continuation to some larger ball. See e. g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%E2%80%93Hadamard_gap_theorem

Comment: @BrunoKrams fixed it.